# Jacoco doesn't include the Robolectic Test coverage

Tags: android, robolectric, jacoco

On my android project jacoco doesn't include the robolectic tests. I can get the android espresso and junit test coverage with jacoco without any issues.

I did see other questions about this issue and all the answers is to upgrade jacoco version. I'm using the latest jacoco version 0.7.9

This is my project main `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.9'

    classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6-rc1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
```

App module build gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    testOptions {
      unitTests.all {
        jacoco {
           includeNoLocationClasses = true
        }
        includeAndroidResources = true
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve that problem with creating a separate task for jacoco in gradle.

First off all you need to add jacoco plugin.

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
```

I didn't add any dependencies as you do on the code snippet above. Just add plugin.

Then add testCoverageEnabled true param to buildTypes section.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

In this example it is in just for debug, but I believe if you add it for release it should also work.

Lastly add jacoco task like below;

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") {

    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R*.class',
                       '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                       '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
            ])
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/testDebug.exec")
    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using that task you should be able to create coverage reports. It will export html formatted coverage report in build folder.
For more information you can look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa).

Comment: Please understand the question. The question here is on the jacoco report, the robolectric test coverages are missing.

Comment: I understand the question. You want to have report for tests which uses robolectirc. I can get jacoco reports including robolectric tests with build.gradle as I described above.

Comment: Ok . it worked . Thanks.

Comment: So please mark it answer and remove the -1 point if you gave it :)

Comment: I can't remove the -1 unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Now you can change.